# How to implement TokenAutoComplete in Xamarin Android

Tags: android, xamarin, xamarin.android, xamarin-studio

I want to implement MultiAutoCompletextview Items with Delete Icon. Can you please help me to this for implementation. how can i do please give me any sample example.

Comment: You want to implement a MultiAutoCompletextview ? Maybe you could read this https://developer.xamarin.com/api/type/Android.Widget.MultiAutoCompleteTextView/

Comment: i want to add remove icon with every item for deleting item.